# VBA word extract first sentence of a paragraph to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, object, ms-word

I have an issue with one of my VBA Word codes which extract every first sentences of  every paragraphs which have more than 200 characters in Excel. My problem is that the code works only on one of my two computers, even though they both have the same Office version. Any idea why? Any idea on how to get the exact same result with another code? Thanks!

```
Sub aHeadlines()
On Error Resume Next
'Word objects

Dim p As Object
Dim s As String

Dim xl
Dim wb, ws, xlr
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Add
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
i = 1

For Each p In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
If Len(p) > 200 Then
Set xlr = ws.Range("a" & i)

  p.Range.Sentences(1).copy
  
  xlr.PasteSpecial 3
  
 i = i + 1

End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: First step, comment out that `On Error Resume Next` and then report back on what line throws an error, and the error message.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! The error message is "PasteSpecial method of range class failed" and the line xlr.PasteSpecial 3 is throwing the error.

Comment: Do you need the formatted sentence, or just the raw text?

Comment: Just the raw text would be perfect!

Comment: Does `xlr.Value = p.Range.Sentences(1).Text` work? (Not a MS Word expert so it may not).

Comment: It does! Thank you!!

Comment: Do be aware that VBA has no idea what a grammatical sentence is. For example, consider the following:
*Mr. Smith spent $1,234.56 at Dr. John's Grocery Store, to buy: 10.25kg of potatoes; 10kg of avocados; and 15.1kg of Mrs. Green's Mt. Pleasant macadamia nuts.*
For you and me, that would count as one sentence; for VBA it counts as 5 sentences.