# Extract paragraphs from word to excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to extract specific paragraphs from word to excel. I have an error with my code about the ".Text" part : "Method or data not found". Any idea why? Thanks!

```
Sub extract()
Dim p As Object
Dim xl
Dim wb, ws, xlr
Dim a As Variant
Dim b As Variant

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Add
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
i = 1 
j = 1 
c = 1 
For Each p In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs

If Len(p) > 200 Then
Set xlr = ws.Range("b" & i)
ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(j).Range.Copy
xlr.Value = ActiveDocument.Range.Paragraphs(j).Text
Set xlr = ws.Range("a" & i)
c = j - 1
If c > 1 Then
ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(c).Range.Copy
xlr.Value = ActiveDocument.Range.Paragraphs(c).Text

End If
ws.Range("c" & i) = Date
i = i + 1
End If

j = j + 1
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA word extract first sentence of a paragraph to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67604909/vba-word-extract-first-sentence-of-a-paragraph-to-excel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ensure that under Tools | Options | Editor you have
   "Require Variable Declaration" checked as shown below. This will
   automatically place `Option Explicit` at the top of each new module
   you create and will prevent you from creating variables without
   declaring them first.

   [image]
2. All variables must be declared in the form `Dim name As DataType`,
   otherwise they default to a datatype of `Variant`
3. Variables that are declared on the same line must each be given a datatype, i.e. `Dim wb As Object, ws As Object, xlr As Object`. Any that don't have a datatype will default to a datatype of `Variant`
4. `.Text` is throwing an error as you have `Range` in the wrong place. It should be `ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(j).Range.Text`. This is something that Intellisense would have shown you as you typed.
5. When coding across Office applications use Tools | References to add the relevant library and avoid using `Object` (aka Late Binding). This will help ensure that the datatypes are correct and make your coding easier. There is no advantage to late binding when you are just using the Office libraries.